# Problems building the openssl crate with Cargo

Tags: linux, rust, archlinux, rust-cargo

Whenever I try to compile I get

```
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: /home/trent/Documents/projects/coding/rust/website/auth/target/debug/deps/libnative_tls-e4af7be01e0cc1c7.rlib(native_tls-e4af7be01e0cc1c7.native_tls.c3tq55qu-cgu.0.rcgu.o): in function `<openssl::stack::StackRef<T>>::len':
          /home/trent/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-0.9.24/src/stack.rs:171: undefined reference to `sk_num'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/trent/Documents/projects/coding/rust/website/auth/target/debug/deps/libnative_tls-e4af7be01e0cc1c7.rlib(native_tls-e4af7be01e0cc1c7.native_tls.c3tq55qu-cgu.0.rcgu.o): in function `<openssl::stack::StackRef<T>>::_get':
          /home/trent/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-0.9.24/src/stack.rs:242: undefined reference to `sk_value'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/trent/Documents/projects/coding/rust/website/auth/target/debug/deps/libopenssl-a51d9ef9dbb88c83.rlib(openssl-a51d9ef9dbb88c83.openssl.27r2wowg-cgu.11.rcgu.o): in function `openssl::ssl::compat::tls_method':
          /home/trent/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-0.9.24/src/ssl/mod.rs:2546: undefined reference to `SSLv23_method'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/trent/Documents/projects/coding/rust/website/auth/target/debug/deps/libopenssl-a51d9ef9dbb88c83.rlib(openssl-a51d9ef9dbb88c83.openssl.27r2wowg-cgu.15.rcgu.o): in function `<openssl::stack::Stack<T>>::new':
          /home/trent/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-0.9.24/src/stack.rs:40: undefined reference to `sk_new_null'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/trent/Documents/projects/coding/rust/website/auth/target/debug/deps/libopenssl-a51d9ef9dbb88c83.rlib(openssl-a51d9ef9dbb88c83.openssl.27r2wowg-cgu.15.rcgu.o): in function `<openssl::stack::Stack<T> as core::ops::drop::Drop>::drop':
          /home/trent/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-0.9.24/src/stack.rs:50: undefined reference to `sk_free'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/trent/Documents/projects/coding/rust/website/auth/target/debug/deps/libopenssl-a51d9ef9dbb88c83.rlib(openssl-a51d9ef9dbb88c83.openssl.27r2wowg-cgu.15.rcgu.o): in function `<openssl::stack::StackRef<T>>::pop':
          /home/trent/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-0.9.24/src/stack.rs:232: undefined reference to `sk_pop'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/trent/Documents/projects/coding/rust/website/auth/target/debug/deps/libopenssl-a51d9ef9dbb88c83.rlib(openssl-a51d9ef9dbb88c83.openssl.27r2wowg-cgu.4.rcgu.o): in function `openssl::version::number':
          /home/trent/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-0.9.24/src/version.rs:51: undefined reference to `SSLeay'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/trent/Documents/projects/coding/rust/website/auth/target/debug/deps/libopenssl-a51d9ef9dbb88c83.rlib(openssl-a51d9ef9dbb88c83.openssl.27r2wowg-cgu.6.rcgu.o): in function `openssl::x509::compat::X509_up_ref':
          /home/trent/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-0.9.24/src/x509/mod.rs:1172: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_add_lock'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/trent/Documents/projects/coding/rust/website/auth/target/debug/deps/libopenssl_sys-51d0c50f2e67767f.rlib(openssl_sys-51d0c50f2e67767f.openssl_sys.afwyjyem-cgu.9.rcgu.o): in function `openssl_sys::init::{{closure}}':
          /home/trent/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-sys-0.9.40/src/lib.rs:150: undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/trent/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-sys-0.9.40/src/lib.rs:151: undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/trent/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-sys-0.9.40/src/lib.rs:152: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/trent/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-sys-0.9.40/src/lib.rs:154: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/trent/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-sys-0.9.40/src/lib.rs:164: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/trent/Documents/projects/coding/rust/website/auth/target/debug/deps/libopenssl_sys-51d0c50f2e67767f.rlib(openssl_sys-51d0c50f2e67767f.openssl_sys.afwyjyem-cgu.9.rcgu.o): in function `openssl_sys::init::set_id_callback':
          /home/trent/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-sys-0.9.40/src/lib.rs:139: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_id_callback'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[Complete log](https://pastebin.com/cyGhJcnp)

I have both OpenSSL and OpenSSL-1.0 installed. I have tried using both Rust stable and nightly. I've also tried to include different versions of the openssl crate, but I think Cargo is just building the version of the crate that I think grpc is using. I'm on Arch Linux.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what code you are even attempting to compile. You can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: Your question may be answered by the answers of [Linking issues using OpenSSL in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12917731/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 4):

Your project is using `openssl 0.9.x` (probably via `tls-api-native-tls 0.1.x` -> `native-tls 0.1.x` -> `openssl 0.9.x`), which doesn't support OpenSSL 1.1.1. I'm also on Arch Linux and I've had to update my programs to `openssl 0.10` in order to use OpenSSL 1.1.1.

In your case, `tls-api-native-tls` needs to be updated to depend on `native-tls 0.2.x`, which uses `openssl 0.10.x` (which does support OpenSSL 1.1.1). [There is an open issue about this.](https://github.com/stepancheg/rust-tls-api/issues/14)

If that's too complicated, you can also use various environment variables to tell `openssl-sys`'s build script which installation of OpenSSL you'd like to use. If you'd prefer using OpenSSL 1.0.x, enter the following commands in your shell:

```
$ cargo clean
$ OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/openssl-1.0 OPENSSL_LIB_DIR=/usr/lib/openssl-1.0 cargo build
```

(Note: the paths above may be specific to Arch Linux.)

For more information on the environment variables you can use to configure `openssl-sys`, see [Manual configuration](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/tree/v0.9.23#manual-configuration).

Comment: The command you have is the same command ive been using to build. I thought i specified that in my post. When i just run `cargo build` i get [this] (https://pastebin.com/XUitrh0D).

Comment: Then the issue might be that the linker finds the OpenSSL 1.1.x libraries before the OpenSSL 1.0.x libraries. In your first build log, I see that `-L native=/usr/lib/openssl-1.0` comes *after* `-L native=/usr/lib`; that might explain why. The missing symbols exist in OpenSSL 1.0.x but not in 1.1.x, so `openssl-sys` thinks it's building against OpenSSL 1.0.x but it's actually linking with OpenSSL 1.1.x.